# How could I preserve netrw :Lexplore in Vim sessions?

Tags: netrw, sessions

I use netrw `:Lexplore` as my file browser and I also use vim sessions. However, whenever I open a session file, `:Lexplore` is closed and I have to re-open.

Is there a way to keep netrw `:Lexplore` open on session save / restore?

Answer (score 1):

As a partial solution: before saving the session, use  `:set bl`  when in the netrw window, thus making it a listed buffer.  Your `sessionoptions` should also have `buffers` as one of its entries.  Then, save a session (ie. `:mksession somefilename`).  Its only a partial solution because the restored window, although the window exists, is filled properly, and netrw works with it, its not named.